# Warning "Variable does not seem to be used in its scope" in foreach

Tags: php, netbeans

I wrote a simple foreach to filter one array and write it's results to another array.

```
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    ...
    $user_email_list[ ] = $user[ "intranet-id" ][ "value" ];
    ...
}
```

Problem is that NetBeans is showing me a warning "Variable does not seem to be used in its scope" on `$user`. If I try to initialize `$user` before foreach, no warning shows. However it doesn't seem to be right.

Is this a NetBeans bug or do I simply misunderstand anything?

I am using NetBeans version 6.7.1 (Build 200907230233) and PHP 5.2.10.

Comment: Code seems fine and Aptana IDE is not complaining. Foreach structure doesn't create a scope in PHP.

Comment: I've just realised that indexes [ "intranet-id" ] and [ "value" ] are cols from table, parsed into an array in different class. NetBeans might have problems with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans might be getting it wrong - the code seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me and I have seen Netbeans make similar mistakes before so I wouldn't worry about it.

Interestingly tho, I just copied your code into Netbeans (I am using the exact same version and build) and didn't get a warning

Comment: Do you have these warnings enabled? Tools->Options->Editor->Hints: check all options.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.. This happens often in NetBeans. Taking one second to look at it and make sure it's wrong is what I usually do. Sometimes closing and re-opening the file makes NetBeans re-parse the file and figure things out. I've also seen re-starting NetBeans do it but that's a pain every time this happens.